# 7 Wonders Duel: Age cards before or after Wonder selection?

Tags: expansions, 7-wonders-duel

I have a question about the initial setup of a 7 Wonders Duel game. In the basic game, the rule book describes the initial setup of the board, then the wonder selection phase, then how to set up the cards for each Age. It's not explicit, but it seems implied that wonders are selected before the Age I cards are dealt out.

With the Pantheon expansion, however, the rules are a bit more explicit. It states:

> Prepare the basic game and the Age I structure. Place 5
>   randomly-selected Mythology tokens face-down on the indicated spaces
>   of the structure, then reveal these tokens. Return the remaining
>   tokens to the box. Perform the Wonders selection phase

Here, it's clear that the Age I cards are dealt before the wonder selection phase. Is the order really different between the base game and the expansion, or are the Age cards always dealt before wonder selection? It won't make a big difference most of the time, but knowing I'll have first dibs on a choice resource among the Age cards could make wonders requiring that resource more attractive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look into rules. Choosing the wonders is part of preparation of game so something done before any age starts. When you have a look on Age description it says:

> At the beginning of each Age, shuffle the corresponding deck, then display the 
>   20  cards

So for me it is quite obvious that you don't know cards when choosing a wonder as preparation of game need to be completed to start first age.

For Pantheon it is even bolded sentence:

> Perform the Wonders selection phase.

As part of setup for age one which comes after instruction to prepare cards.

So in fact it looks order is different with addition than in main game.